# FFmpeg tile cropping

Tags: ffmpeg, tile, android-ffmpeg

This image is splitted to 12 equal pieces.
Is there any way to do such a work with ffmpeg?

[image: this images was uploaded on Instagram]

Comment: Probably easier using `convert` from ImageMagick. Is that a viable alternative for you? See its [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) option (scroll down for many examples). Otherwise using `ffmpeg` you will need to use one crop filter per segment and provide the coordinates for each.

Comment: @llogan I am using ffmpeg in my android app so I can not use ImageMagic. I think I have to use crop option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -vf "crop=iw/3:ih/4:mod(n,3)*iw/3:trunc(n/3)*ih/4" -vframes 12 out%d.png
```

For full coverage of image, the image width has to be divisible by 3, and height by 4.

---

For square output, set crop height to crop width. The vertical crop leaves some space at top and bottom.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -vf "crop=iw/3:iw/3:mod(n,3)*iw/3:trunc(n/3)*iw/3+(ih-iw)/2" -vframes 12 out%d.png
```

(This method requires that ih/4 > iw/3 for desired output)

Comment: I wanna prepare the output for Instagram, so every single of the output images should be in a square size.Do you have any idea for this? For example think of an image with this resolution: 500 for width and 700 for height. in this case we divide the width by 3 and it should be ~166. indeed we should have 166x166 images in output. And also for height of this image we will have 36 extra pixels. I was wondering if you has any idea that I can start cropping from x=0,y=18(36/2)

Comment: I had to escape the comma in `mod(n,3)` to get this to work: `mod(n\,3)`